# Reserved function names in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, event-handling, reserved-words

After renaming my function the code stopped working. That new name `scrollIntoView` seems to be clashing with the [`element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method.

```
<div onmousedown="scrollIntoView('id001')"/>

function scrollIntoView(id) {
    alert(id);
}
```

I've created a simple test case https://jsfiddle.net/mgtn215y/ which has shown my function is simply ignored in favor of `element.scrollIntoView()` even

- it is not called on element
- attributes do not match

The solution is obvious - to use a different function name. As this behavior is consistent across major browsers, I expect this is specified somewhere. However, I couldn't find anything related in e.g. [JavaScript lexical grammar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar). Is there any background for this behavior?

Comment: In this context, `element` is an `Element` object referring to the element for which the function is triggered. Examining the div element by calling `getElementById` reveals that is has a scrollIntoView() function, just like any other Element, and since the scope of the `onmousedown` event is the element itself, it favors this function over the global function you have created. A possible solution would be what Juniorized suggested below.

Comment: http://www.jibbering.com/faq/names/event_handler.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the scope chain of functions compiled from HTML element attribute values declared in HTML source. Attributes of the form `on_eventName=functionBodyCode` exhibit this behavior.

For historical reasons (the DOM did not exist in its current form, `document.getElementByID` had yet to be invented...) such functions are compiled with a scope chain comprising the object on which the event handler attribute is provided, any `form` element the element is within, and the `document` object. *However* different browsers took different approaches when emulating Netscape behavior.  Some browsers included any and every parent object of an element providing an event handler attribute, while others omitted some pertinent objects such as `document`.

Technical detail may be found in "Javascript the definitive guide" O'Reilly, section "19.1.6. Scope of Event Handlers".

The main recommendation is to avoid supplying event handlers in HTML - add them in JavaScript using `addEventListener` instead. If for some reason function calls must be coded in HTML attribute values, avoid using function names that are methods of DOM objects.

Note the custom scope chain for event handlers only applies to functions generated from HTML attributes. It does **not** apply to functions created in JavaScript and added to an element using `addEventListener` or `element.onEventName=aFunctionObject`.

---

The following snippet demonstrates locating property names of outer elements in the scope chain of event handlers defined in HTML: :

```html
<form name="formName1" action="">
<p> Try to access the elements collection of the form:
   <button type="button"
      onclick="console.log( elements);">elements
   </button>
</p>

</form>
<form name="formName2" action="" onsubmit="return false">
<p> Try to access form name as form.name:
  <button type="button"
     onclick="console.log( 'form.name: %s', form.name);">form.name
  </button>
</p>
</form>

<form name="formName3" action="" onsubmit="return false">
<p>Access document.write as "write"
   <button type="button"
      onclick="console.log( 'write: %s', write);">write
   </button>
</p>
</form>
```

- In the first form, `elements` is a property of the surrounding form element.
- In the second form, `form` is a property of the HTMLButtonElement.
- In the third form, `write` is a method of `document`.
- Citing in 2020, HTML5 specifies the scope chain for HTML attribute handlers as "element > outer form element > document" under "**Scope**" within numbered list item 3.9 of [internal raw uncompiled handler](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#internal-raw-uncompiled-handler).

Comment: Another workaround: `onmousedown="window.scrollIntoView('id1001')"`

Comment: So this is browser-specific, not part of the JS spec?

Comment: @Barmar As expected it's not part of ECMAScript - which is not about HTML applications in particular. The scope chain dates from HTML3 or earlier, and while I do recall discussion of it on comp_lang_javasscript it was long ago. I have not been able to find mention of it in published HTML standards. Further investigation (see code snippet) shows the element with the HTML attribute function and the document object are in scope, but current browsers are not including the form element

Comment: Backtrack - the form element is in scope, I just used a property name "name"  which was available on the button element as an empty string. Answer updated. ( @Barmar )

Comment: Updated with reference to HTML standard.

Answer (score 2):

For some strange reason, it looks like inline handlers implicitly use `with(this)` when they run, where `this` references the element that triggered the event. Whenever you try to reference something, if that something exists as a property of `this`, then *that property* will end up being referenced, rather than an outer variable with the same name:

```js
console.log(typeof className); // Undefined in standard global scope
console.log(typeof scrollIntoView); // Undefined in standard global scope
```

```css
.mydiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv" onclick="
  console.log(typeof className); // Defined inside inline handler
  console.log(typeof scrollIntoView); // Defined inside inline handler
">
```

To the interpreter, the `onclick` *actually* looks something more like:

```
onclick="with(this) {
  console.log(typeof className);
  console.log(typeof scrollIntoView);
}"
```

It's pretty strange. But inline event handlers are terrible practice anyway, and probably shouldn't be used; assign the handler properly with `addEventListener` or `onkeydown` instead:

```js
document.querySelector('.mydiv').onmousedown = () => scrollIntoView("id001");
function scrollIntoView(id) {
  console.log(id);
}
```

```css
.mydiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
    <div class="mydiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To override, simply try:

```
Element.prototype.scrollIntoView = function(id) {
    alert(id);
}
```

But do note that it works with `addEventListener`:

```js
var element = document.getElementById("element");

function scrollIntoView(id) {
    alert(id);
}

element.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    scrollIntoView("id001");
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```