# Switch the text inside a div box on the right to the div box on the left and vice versa by clicking buttons

Tags: javascript

I need to ask user's input by clicking a button "start" and display it in a div box on the left, then there are 2 buttons which can switch the text from left box to right and another button to switch the text back to left, after all another button to clear it. I'm stuck on the switching part and the clear part. My clear script got some problem and it can't clear the content. I have no idea how to start on the switching part.

This is my code:

```
<html>
<style>
.container{
width:900px;
height:200px;
}

.grey-box{
background-color:grey;
width:300px;
height:200px;
float:right;
}

.black-box{
background-color:black;
width:300px;
height:200px;
float:left;
}

.button{
position:relative;
left:110px;
top:50px;
}
</style>

<script>
function start(){
var name = prompt("Please enter your name");

document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name;
}

function clear(){
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = ""; 
}
</script>
<button onClick="start();">Start</button>
<button onClick="clear()">Clear</button>
<br/ ><br />

<div class="container">
<div class="black-box" id="leftBox"><p id="name" style="color:white;text- 
align:center;margin:100px;"></p></div>

<div class="grey-box" id="rightBox"></div>

<div class="button">
    <button onClick="le2ri()">--></button><br /><br />
    <button onClick="ri2le()"><--</button>
</div>
</div>

</html>
```

Ideally I would like to have page like this, after entering the input it will be shown on the left box initially, when i press to right button the user input will be going to the right box. When i press to left button the user input will be going to the left.[image]

Comment: what have you tried in regard to that? You can clear the input box and `append` the html to the one on the right and vice versa for example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reserved function names in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52599614/reserved-function-names-in-javascript)

Comment: The clear function is not working because it is calling `document.clear' - see the proposed [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52599614/reserved-function-names-in-javascript).  _Please avoid asking multiple questions at once._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, clicking the buttons would simply copy the textContent from each and place it in the other box. Don't call your function `clear()` as it is referring to [`Document.clear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/clear).

Your clear function would be always shadowed by the `document.clear()` so you would be needing to change the name of the function responsible for clearing text.

```html
<html>
<style>
.container{
width:900px;
height:200px;
}

.grey-box{
background-color:grey;
width:300px;
height:200px;
float:right;
}

.black-box{
background-color:black;
width:300px;
height:200px;
float:left;
}

.button{
position:relative;
left:110px;
top:50px;
}
</style>

<script>
function start(){
var name = prompt("Please enter your name");

document.getElementById("name").textContent = name;
}
function clearText(){
document.getElementById("name").textContent = ""; 
}

function le2ri(){
document.getElementById("rightBox").textContent = document.getElementById("name").textContent
document.getElementById("name").textContent = "";
}
function ri2le(){
document.getElementById("name").textContent = document.getElementById("rightBox").textContent
document.getElementById("rightBox").textContent = "";
}

</script>
<button onclick="start();">Start</button>
<button onclick="clearText();">Clear</button>


<br/ ><br />

<div class="container">
<div class="black-box" id="leftBox"><p id="name" style="color:white;text- 
align:center;margin:100px;"></p></div>

<div class="grey-box" id="rightBox"></div>

<div class="button">
    <button onClick="le2ri()"> To right </button><br /><br />
    <button onClick="ri2le()"> To left </button>
</div>
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .container {
        width: 900px;
        height: 200px;
      }

      .grey-box {
        background-color: grey;
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        float: right;
      }

      .black-box {
        background-color: black;
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        float: left;
      }

      .button {
        position: relative;
        left: 110px;
        top: 50px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onClick="start()">Start</button>
    <button onClick="clearField()">Clear</button>
    <br /><br />

    <div class="container">
      <div class="black-box" id="leftBox">
        <p style="color:white;text-align:center;margin:100px;"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="grey-box" id="rightBox">
        <p style="color:white;text-align:center;margin:100px;"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="button">
        <button onClick="leftRight()">Move Right</button>
        <br /><br />
        <button onClick="rightLeft()">Move Left</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    // dom reference
    const blackBox = document.querySelector("#leftBox");
    const greyBox = document.querySelector("#rightBox");

    let name;

    // start function
    function start() {
      name = prompt("Please enter your name");

      // make sure user input something
      if (name !== "") {
        blackBox.children[0].innerHTML = name;
      } else {
        alert("Type your name.");
      }
    }

    // left 2 right function
    function leftRight() {
      // setting first box to empty
      blackBox.children[0].innerHTML = "";
      // adding name value to the right box
      greyBox.children[0].innerHTML = name;
    }

    // left 2 right function
    function rightLeft() {
      // setting first box to empty
      blackBox.children[0].innerHTML = name;
      // adding name value to the right box
      greyBox.children[0].innerHTML = "";
    }

    function clearField() {
      // clearing out the fields and the name value
      blackBox.children[0].innerHTML = "";
      greyBox.children[0].innerHTML = "";
      name = "";
    }
  </script>
</html>
```