# "onclick" and "this" in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, this, onclicklistener

I am confused:

- why with inline onlick, we have to write onclick="hello()", but in JS, we should write btn.onclick=hello or btn.addEventListener('click',hello);
- for regular function, why with inline onlick, "this" refers to window, but with js call, "this" refers to button.
- I don't understand last two buttons

according to w3school, In a function, this refers to the global object.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp

In regular functions the this keyword represented the object that called the function, which could be the window, the document, a button or whatever. 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp

```js
const arrayBtn = document.querySelector(".arrowFunc");
const regBtn = document.querySelector(".regFunc");
hello = () => console.log("i am arrow function" + this);
function hiii(){
  console.log("i am regular function" + this);
}
arrayBtn.addEventListener("click", hello);
regBtn.addEventListener("click", hiii);
```

```html
<button onclick="hello()">This calls an arrow function with an inline onclick</button>
<button class="arrowFunc">This calls an arrow function with event listener</button>
<button onclick="hiii()">This calls an regular function with an inline onclick</button>
<button class="regFunc">This calls an regular function with event listener</button>
<button onclick="function tes(){console.log(this)}tes()">button</button>
<button onclick="console.log(this)">button</button>
```

```
[Log] i am arrow function[object Window] <br>
[Log] i am arrow function[object Window] <br>
[Log] i am regular function[object Window] <br>
[Log] i am regular function[object HTMLButtonElement] <br>
[Log] Window {document: #document, window: Window, NaN: NaN, nalert: function, obj: {name: "my_obj"}, …} <br>
[Log] <button onclick="console.log(this)">button</button>
```

Comment: I'm also confused about this even after being a developer for years !

Comment: Also, try to link MDN rather than W3Schools as a source. It is more official.

Comment: What's to understand? You wrote how `this` context is interpreted already. `this`, in a regular function, within the method *(function)* of an Object, refers to the Object, which in the case of an Event is the Element. So the function assigned to the `onclick` of a Element is the method, and the button is the Object. `this` within an Arrow function scopes up to wherever your last scope is, global if not within a class or constructor. Note that a constructor is a function. It only becomes an Object upon calling `new` on it.

Answer (score 3):

#### about `this` values.

1. Arrow functions capture and *always* use their lexical  `this` value, meaning the one that was in effect when their [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) was evaluated. Evaluation usually occurs when executing an assignment operation or when calculating parameter values for a function call which has arrow functions in its argument list.

   - Arrow functions cannot be used as constructors.
2. Non arrow functions called as constructors using [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) (or [`super`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) when extending a class) see the object under construction as  their `this` value.
3. Bound functions save and use a `this value` supplied as the first argument to the [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) of another function.

   - Bound functions ignore their saved `this` value if called as constructors - but this is rare enough to be considered an edge case and is  [*not generally recommended*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Bound_functions_used_as_constructors).
   - Binding an arrow function has no effect on its `this` value but could be used to predefine a set of parameter values.
4. Functions called using either their [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) object methods take their `this` value from the (first) `thisValue` argument supplied to `call` or `apply`, subject to JavaScript mode:

   - In strict mode `null` or `undefined` values provided for `thisValue` are used as  the function's `this` value. In [sloppy mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Sloppy_mode) however, `null` or `undefined` are replaced by `window` before making the call.
   - Arrow and bound functions can be called using these methods (e.g. to supply arguments) but use their own recorded `this` value.
5. ***Provided none of the preceding rules apply***, functions explicitly called as a method of an object use the object as their `this` value.

   E.G. in a call of form

   ```
   someObject.methodName( optionalArgumentList)
   ```

   `this` in `methodName` refers to `someObject` if the method is a regular function.
6. In strict mode, the default value of `this` in an unqualified function call is `undefined`. In sloppy mode (dating from when JavaScript was first introduced) `this` is `window`. For demonstration:

```js
function a () {
    "use strict";
    console.log("in strict mode functions the default this is ", this);
};
let b = function() {
    console.log("but in non strict mode,  the default this is ",
        this === window ? "window" : this
    );
}

a(); // undefined
b(); // window
```

7. Code provided as a text string in calls to the global [Function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function),  [`SetTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), related timer calls, and event attributes in HTML source, is treated as a "script" in its own right and creates
   a function that

   - operates in sloppy mode if strict mode *is not* invoked by the supplied source code,
   - operates in strict mode if strict mode *is* invoked in the source.

   While this alters the *default* `this` value of the function, is is also an edge case because none of these methods of creating a function is recommended when writing maintainable code.
8. The `this` value when evaluating code with [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) is outside the scope of this question, but for completeness:

   - Direct calls to `eval` inherit `this` from the calling context unless the evaluated code invokes strict mode - in which case `this` is `undefined` during code evaluation.
   - Indirect calls to `eval` use `window` (i.e.  the global object) as `this` *even if they invoke strict mode* ([Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Descriptionhttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Description).)

   This is also an edge case since because of its dangers, `eval` should [never be used because you can](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!).

---

### Inline event handlers in HTML

Event handler content attributes in an HTML tag of the form

```
    onEventName="text"
```

are converted into event handler functions by the **HTML parser** using  steps equivalent to

1. Save the text as the attribute's string value.
2. Use the JavaScript parser/compiler to create an event handler function from the text by including it in a template of form

   ```
   function( event) {
         // include attribute text here as body code
   }
   ```
3. Save the function as a property of the element under the same name as the attribute. E.G. at this point an element with an `onclick` text attribute will also have an `onclick` property which is a function.
4. Add the function to the element's internal [event handler map.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#activate-an-event-handler)  In practical terms this means actual event handling uses a map of listeners rather than looking for handler functions on the element.

**Warning**

- HTML onEventName attributes predate both standardization of the DOM and the introduction of `addEventListener`:

  Handlers created by the HTML parser have a legacy scope chain that minimally searches the element the event attribute belongs to, a surrounding `form` element if any, and the `document` object before reaching the global object when looking up names - which can result in [obscure bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52599614/5217142).

---

**question 1**

> Why with inline onlick, we have to write onclick="hello()", but in JS, we should write btn.onclick=hello or btn.addEventListener('click',hello);

The HTML event handler attribute is used as the body code of a event handler function created by the HTML parser. To call `hello`, attribute text *must provide the source code to make the call*, as in e.g. `hello()`.

In JS, setting an `onclick` to a function object, or calling `addEventListener` with a function as the second parameter, adds the function to a map of handlers associated with the element. If parentheses are placed after the function name, using `onclick` as an example:

```
  onclick = myFunction();
```

the function is called and an attempt is made to use its return value as a handler function - and if the return value is not a function little happens. Most often this is a mistake and not the desired outcome.

---

**question 2**

> For regular function, why with inline onclick, "this" refers to window, but with js call, "this" refers to button.

Inside the event handler function created from an inline onclick attribute, `this` *does* refer to the button. If you call out to another function with code like `hello()`, you are making an unqualified call to it, so the called function uses its default `this` value - i.e. `window` if the called function operates in sloppy mode.

Following on from "Inline event handlers in HTML", you *could* pass on `this` (referring to the button) and the `event` object as a parameter  values if you wanted to:

```
onclick="hello(this, event)"
```

Handler functions provided in JavaScript go directly into the element's map of event handlers and are called by the event system with the button as their `this` value (probably using `call` or `apply`, since handlers added with `addEventListener` aren't maintained as element property values).

---

**question 3**

> `<button onclick="function tes(){console.log(this)}tes()">button>/button>`

Creates the event handler function

```
function onclick(event) {
    function tes(){
        console.log(this)
    }
    tes()
}
```

Strict mode was not invoked in the button tag's event attribute text, so both `onclick` and  `tes` are in sloppy mode. `tes` is called without qualification, so it uses and logs its default `this` value which is `window`.

In regards to  "about this values", none of rules 1 - 5 apply, so rule 6 comes into effect.

---

**question 4**

> `<button onclick="console.log(this)">button</button>`

creates a handler function

```
function onclick(event) {
    console.log(this)
}
```

which is called with the button element as its `this` value by the event system as it would for any other handler. `console.log` is showing the outer HTML for the button in the log. If you change `this` to a string, the log will tell you its an HTMLButtonElement element instead:

```html
<button onclick="console.log(this.toString())">button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The text `hello()` in the inline `<button onclick="hello()">` is actually a small JavaScript program itself — you should never use this; it’s an obsolete old-fashioned way to make anything work and should be forgotten.

Instead, the correct way in JavaScript is like this:

```js
function hello(){}

button.addEventListener("click", hello);
```

where `hello` is the name of a function (not a JavaScript program).

As for why `this` is the current button? All functions can be called with a different `this`.

You can call the `hello` function with a different `this` if you want to.

```js
hello.call({ turkey: true });
```

That’s how you call `hello` and provide `{ turkey: true }` as the `this` object.

It’s standard for HTML elements to call event handlers with the element as the `this` object.