# Why does wrapping a callback in an anonymous function change the meaning of 'this'?

Tags: javascript, this

If I have a method that uses the keyword `this`:

```js
let myObject = {
    logThis: function(){
        console.log(this)
    },
}
```

And I pass it to a `higherOrder` function:

```js
function higherOrder(callback){
    callback()
}

higherOrder(obj.logThis)
```

`this` will not refer to `myObject`, but to the object that calls `higherOrder` (in this case, the window object).
I understand that this is because its execution context changes.

what I **dont** understand is why when I wrap it in an anonymous function like this:

```js
higherOrder(function(){myObject.logThis()})
```

`this` will again refer to `myObject`. Isn't the execution context still changing?
If i'm passing it to a function that exists in the global scope, shouldn't `this` refer to the global scope?
I can't figure out why wrapping it in an anonymous function should change anything.

Comment: I answered a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58072653/5217142), which answers the question about the call form `myObject.logThis()` under point 5. `window` shows up as the `this` value when the call is unqualified  ( `callback()` in the post) because the code is not in strict mode (point 6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an anonymous function wraps MyObj in a closure. That closure's lexical scope (execution context) is now localized to the closure. So `this` is localized to the closure (and MyObj) as well.

You can discover that by using a debugger with a break point set on the `callback()` call.

This image shows the variable structure with the closure in place:

[image: With anonymous function wrapper]

Without the function wrapper, the lexical scope is the same scope as the `higherOrder()` function - which is the global scope. Again, this is demonstrated with a break point on the same line of code (note lack of closure):

[image: Without wrapper]

Note: this code is run in node - so no Window object here.